# Read the transfer value from e1=Entry(root) and take it with you into the new function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
def fahrradfuerhrdoku ():
        print (e1.get())
        
        
def button_searchdata():
        root = Tk()
        root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        root.geometry('400x200')
        command=create_window
        root.title("Fahrradsuche für HR Doku")
        Label(root, text="R-Nummer ohne R").place(x = 30, y = 72, width=100, height=50)
        e1 = Entry(root)
        e1.place(x = 150, y = 80, width=200, height=30)
        Button(root, text='suchen', command=fahrradfuerhrdoku).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to ensure that when a user makes an entry via e1 = Entry "e.g. 123456", the "Fahrradfuerhrdoku" function receives the value "123456" and I can continue working with it in the function.

However, when I run print (e1.get()) in the function above, Python tells me that e1 is undefined. I thought it has the value that is entered by entry.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367815/error-message-saying-variable-not-defined-when-it-is-python

Comment: Put this out of function root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x = 150, y = 80, width=200, height=30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the e1 variable global in the function so you can use it outside of the function , like this:

```
def fahrradfuerhrdoku ():
        print (e1.get())
        
        
def button_searchdata():
        #makes e1 global
        global e1
        root = Tk()
        root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        root.geometry('400x200')
        root.title("Fahrradsuche für HR Doku")
        Label(root, text="R-Nummer ohne R").place(x = 30, y = 72, width=100, height=50)
        e1 = Entry(root)
        e1.place(x = 150, y = 80, width=200, height=30)
        Button(root, text='suchen', command=fahrradfuerhrdoku).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        root.mainloop()
```

or you need to put e1 out of the function so its reachable by the function 'fahrradfuerhrdoku' , like this :

```
def fahrradfuerhrdoku ():
        print (e1.get())
        
        
def button_searchdata():
        root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        root.geometry('400x200')
        root.title("Fahrradsuche für HR Doku")
        Label(root, text="R-Nummer ohne R").place(x = 30, y = 72, width=100, height=50)
        Button(root, text='suchen', command=fahrradfuerhrdoku).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x = 150, y = 80, width=200, height=30)
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you would explain why your answer solves the issue.